# How to run a script with root authority in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, cgi, root

I have to develop a Web site written in CGI.

I would like to know how to run a script with root authority from CGI.

Let's say the script name is `hello`, I run it from CGI like **system("pathToTheFile/hello")**.

Now I would like to run this hello file as root; can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Now I've to write a file in my system using a script but I need root authority to write a file.

Comment: BTW you should think about the ramification of allowing a webpage to get a root access.

Comment: Normally the web-server you run to access your CGI script should be run on a system user ad not under root (e.g. a user calles  `apache` who execute the apache httpd); after you just give that user the read and execute access to the script.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the safest way to do this kind of thing is to use the *setuid* feature of UNIX-like OSs. If you set the owner of the `hello` program to be `root`, and then set the setuid bit:

```
chmod u+s hello
```

Then no matter *who* executes the program, it will execute as root. This works for native executables, but not for interpreted scripts. If "hello" has to be a script, then this won't work for you.

Now, I have to say that in general, setuid root programs aren't a great idea. Often you can create a special user to own the script, and give that user some limited privileges needed, and then make the script setuid to that user.

Comment: No, that does not work for scripts. Only binaries. Also, *you* can't set that, that would be a big security hole. The existing root account would have to set that. That might be you, however.

Comment: @Keith, you _could_ have a script which runs a specially modified setuid shell (a "real" executable) passing another script as the parameter. This would get around that problem. Convoluted, yes, but there are ways around most problems.

Comment: @pax, true but you still have to setuid some binary somewhere. And this post didn't mention that extra step, so I thought I would. Also, I disagree that it's the safest way, since "no matter who executes" it it gets the elevated privileges. `sudo` is safer since you can define more fine-grained control over who can execute it (e.g. the UID of the web server only).

Comment: @Keith appears to be right: Linux doesn't allow setuid scripts at all. I had this belief that it was at least configurable, but that doesn't seem to to be the case; perhaps it once was. *BSD Unices, including OS X, allow them, and that's where I spend more of my time these days. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes some older *nix do allow it, but [Linux doesn't](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).  A good discussion about the history of it is [here](http://www.unix.com/302112883-post3.html).

Answer (score 1):

The normal method would be to have the executable file owned by the user you want to run it as, then set the [SUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit.

The method of using `sudo` usually requires user input for the password (there are ways around this but they're hideously complex).

I suppose I don't need to mention that setting the SUID bit is a very dangerous thing to do, yes? If there's *any* other way to do what you want, you should use it.

---

One thing you may want to consider is to pose the question not in terms of the solution you need but in terms of the problem you want solved. Running as root is a *solution* and not necessarily a good one. Post *what* you're trying to achieve rather than *how,* and we can help you out in a far less dangerous way.

Answer (score 1):

A much safer method of doing things as root from a web page is to disconnect the program execution from the web page. Instead, use Unix local sockets, named pipes, or a directory of queued jobs.

The directory is probably the easiest to handle. Set up a directory that your web page can write files into. When your page needs something done, write a file describing the job. Then you have a program running as root waiting for new jobs. It can run continuously if it needs fast response or it can run every minute or every few minutes using a crontab entry.