# Managing processes with PHP web interface

Tags: php, apache

I have a project that I am working on that requires me to manage (Stop, start, restart) a script using a web interface.  This script was started as a cron job on boot.

The problem is that the script has to be run with root access.  Is there a way to do this somewhat securely with a PHP/Apache?

If not how could I go about managing this script using a web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was  unable to get the shell_exec method to work, so I set up a table in the database and updated a value in that table with PHP.  I have a Python watchdog that runs using Cron to check the value in that table.  If it finds that the script start command has been sent, it starts the script, or performs one of several different actions.  This works well and avoids the use of the controversial SETUID, and apache doesn't need any special permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an executable to manage the script and run that from the PHP page with shell_exec.  Then it's the executable that needs to have SETUID as root.

In Linux this only works for a native executable not shell scripts, see this discussion:
[How to run a script with root authority in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119254/how-to-run-a-script-with-root-authority-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks Dave.  This has me going in the correct direction.  Do you have any advice on launching a python script with an executable?  Preferable C++? All the research I have done turns up seemingly needlessly complex answers.  My thought is PHP-> C++ executable -> python.py, and 'close' the C++ executable.  Should be easy right?